# Practicality of storing long uncut logs

Tags: trees, storage

I'm not sure what community to post this under so please let me know if this should be in a different place.

I am about to cut down a lot of trees (15-20) on my property and will be using the wood for burning in a wood stove. However, I don't have the time to immediately cut everything and split the wood. I was thinking about just cutting the trees into 6 foot logs and stacking those until I can get to them at a later time. Some of them may sit for a couple of years before they eventually get cut and split. Is there anything bad about letting the 6 ft logs sit outside that long before splitting them for firewood? I feel this method is the most practical for my situation where I'm limited by time and I have a lot of trees to process.

The logs would be stored outside and stacked to allow airflow (off the ground too). Most of the trees are hardwoods.

Comment: "hardwood" is very generic. Some wood do no like rain, some requires it (to avoid crackles and sparks).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wood should be left to cure outside before being used as firewood so I don't see any negatives to this. It should be covered to stop it getting wet though.

Alternatively you could turn all the hardwood into shiitake mushrooms, sell those, and buy in firewood while making a profit!

Answer (score 2):

You are describing the usual (historical) method: cutting trees into logs (long, or also short to 3 feet), get them some air and rain (depending on the species of tree), store them in wood, from time to time bring them to home (in a outside depot), and regularly (weekly to daily) cut the old ones so that they can be used.

To me, it seems that because it is hard work, and we are no more so used on hard work, now we tend to ask professional to deliver us wood in a already ready for burning. And because professional did it (for us), it seems that it is the correct way.

Note: it depends on species, how many years (1 to 3-5) they should be stored (as logs).

So, you can do it. The more you cut logs, the more it need some sort of cover for rain. Usually long logs on bottom, to keep other logs from wet soil, and some tarp on top.

Answer (score 1):

Depending where you are it could be a termite farm. In east TX, also good for growing roaches, assorted lizards, certain birds like Carolina Wrens,etc. Personally , I think wood piles are over-rated for growing snakes. Did you consider selling the logs ; likely need a minimum size of 16" diameter and 12 ft length, straight ? I think it would be better to cut about 2 ft lengths while you are cutting , easier to move and stack. And if you have Tulip, Birch, Poplar ; oyster mushrooms would be good to try.